# In Oracle Apex how do you create a Select List with sub-lists?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to create a Select List where some values can have a list of sub-values, like this:[image]][1

Answer (score 0):

You can't (at least, as far as I can tell).

What you could do, is to create **two** select list items (or any number of them) so that they represent a **cascade**, which means that the 1st item is "master". The 2nd item contains its own query which - in its `where` clause - references the 1st item which is also to be set as the **parent item** for the 2nd item.

And so forth, for all cascading items.

Comment: Thanks but I already know about this. I was specifically asked to create a dropdown menu that has submenus. Possible someone created a plugin to do it?

Comment: If it were about *menu* (e.g. on the left hand side of the screen), then yes - you can do it in Apex. If it is just a *select list item* (or pop-up, whatever), then (once again - as far as I know) you can't do it in Apex. I don't know whether there's a plugin. Personally, I don't like using 3rd party plugins because there's no guarantee that they'll work in future Apex versions. As you have to upgrade Apex (sooner or later), plugin that used to work doesn't work any more. If person(s) who created plugin don't maintain it any more, you'll have a BIG problem. But that's just me.

Comment: Technically this explains how to do it: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/menu-popup, but it's creating a region of type List instead of a Select List page item. How can I detect the value the user picks from this list region instead of just having it be a list of target links?

Comment: Cool, that really looks like what you wanted! I've never seen (obviously) nor used (obviously) it, so - I wouldn't know how to set it to do what you wanted, sorry. And - obviously - my "answer" is completely useless.

Comment: I've tried and it's of no use. This "List region" is designed for limited use cases that don't include acting like a Select List.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I hoped it would work ...

Comment: I wonder if the list items could each pass a difference value (MENU1, MENU1A, etc) in the URL to set a page item on your target page?
Then on page load, test that item value?

Also, have you checked apex.world for a possible plug-in?